# in auto complete search i want to fetch the data from tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

in auto complete search i want to fetch the data from tableview.i used below codes for auto search but its not auto search. please help me if any one know

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {
    // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
    // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
    [autoCompleteData removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString *curString in pastData) {
        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.length!= 0) {
            [autoCompleteData addObject:curString];  
        }
    }
    [routeName reloadData];
}
```

Comment: check with break points.

Comment: where...sorry pls tell me detail. i'm new to iphone.

Comment: check weather this method was calling or not?

Comment: @vishnu Sunny means you put a breakpoint in the `[autoCompleteData removeAllObjects];` line, run your project, if it paused at this line means that that method is called, otherwise your code isn't being executed.

Comment: If you are using a `UITextField` to enter your search, I recommend you put all the code above in the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`. More details here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW4

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your data on each keystroke. You can catch each keystroke of a text field in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.

I would suggest you just filter the data array of your table view and `reloadData`. With predicates you can do the filtering with lightening speed and very little code:

```
autoCompleteData = [currentDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", search text]];
```